# Laravel Socialite not returning user data

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I configured Laravel Socialite and it was returning user data. I discovered that the data structure was changed. `$user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();` is not returning name, email and avater. Please anyone know what happened to the facebook, google and twitter.

Here are snapshots of the providers:

[Facebook Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAx7P.png)

[Google Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjgE0.png)

So if any body have a solution to this or what am doing wrong. Please help.

Comment: What does `dd($user)` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by wrapping my callback method in a try catch block, then I recreated my CreateOrLogin class, it now accesses Socialite::driver('facebook')->user() directly as the documentation was stated.